# RDLC File returning LocalProcessingException Error

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio-2010, rdlc

When I try to render a `.rdlc` file I am receiving a

> LocalProcessingException was unhandled by user code

I have looked at my `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\ReportingServices\Microsoft.ReportingServices.targets` file and it reads:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
   <UsingTask TaskName="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlCompile" 
              AssemblyName="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>"
```

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and targeting .NET Framework 4.0. When I dive deeper into the error I find the error:

> The report definition is not valid.
>   Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I worked back through my changes and have found that I had inadvertently converted the RDLC to  to RDLC 2008 which in turn caused the error(s).